# PRML - Bishop: Order of Addition - Variance calculation

Tags: machine-learning, probability

My question is related to section 3.2: Bias-Variance decomposition.
My doubt is specific to formula for variance (3.47, below), on pg 150 - 151.

**Background:**
General formula for variance is:

$\begin{align*} variance = E_{\mathcal D} [\{y(\mathbf x;\mathcal D) - E_{\mathcal D}[y(\mathbf x; \mathcal D)]\}^2] \end{align*} \tag{3.40}$

where:

1. $y(\mathbf x;\mathcal D)$: output based on prediction model for  dataset $\mathcal D \in L \, (one\,of\,100\, datasets)$ $\implies $ there'll be 100 outputs, 1 for each of 100 models.
2. $E_{\mathcal D}[y(\mathbf x; \mathcal D)]$: Average of prediction for respective dataset $\mathcal D$ $\implies $ there'll be 100 mean values, 1 per model.
3. $\begin{align*} \{y(\mathbf x;\mathcal D) - E_{\mathcal D} [y(\mathbf x; \mathcal D)]\}^2 \end{align*}$ : squared-difference w.r.t mean for $\mathcal D$ $\implies $ similarly 100 squared errors.
4. $E_{\mathcal D} [.]:$ averaged squared error, across **all** datasets $\mathcal D$, as calculated above

pls. note: *$E$* stands for Expectation (average, in probability).

There're $\mathbf {L=100}$ datasets, each containing $\mathbf {N=25} $ data points.

Step 1-Modelling:- On the basis of analysis of *n* data points of a dataset *l*, we model a prediction formula $y^{(l)}(.)$ that outputs value - for an input *x*, based on model specific to that dataset.

Step 2 - Prediction (Calculate ***mean*** of predictions across models) : for any point x, take the mean of predictions $\bar y$, across models:
$\begin{align*} \bar y = \frac {1}{L} \sum_{l=1}^L y^{(l)}(x) \end{align*}$

And then, the author goes on to calculate variance as:

$\begin{align*} variance = \frac {1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac {1}{L} \sum_{l=1}^L \{y^{(l)}(x_n) - \bar y(x_n)\}^2 \end{align*} \tag{ 3.47}$

**Question:**

Even though addition is commutative, my doubt is at conceptual level related to ordering of summation:

Shouldn't we first choose a dataset *l* from L (outer loop/ sum), and then find the variance - average of mean-squared error - over all data points, *n* $\in$ N - of that dataset  (inner loop/ sum); i.e. shouldn't the equation be:

$\begin{align*} \frac {1}{L} \sum_{l=1}^L \frac {1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \{y^{(l)}(x_n) - \bar y(x_n)\}^2 \end{align*}$

I would appreciate if you can guide me on this.

The above-mentioned book is [freely available on Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/pattern-recognition-machine-learning/) research portal.

P.S.: Shifted his question from *Mathematics* to *Cross Validation* - as suggested by fellow learner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two formulas give exactly the same answer. However, the one in the book might sometimes be easier to implement, as $\bar y(x_n)$ is constant during the inner loop, so you only need to store or compute $\bar y(x_n)$ for the current $n$.  With your version, the inner loop needs all the values of $\bar y(x_n)$

Comment: I guess I got your explanation. Would appreciate if you can confirm/ flag the understanding:
Variance calculation: i)Take first of $\mathbf N = 25$ points (outer loop) -> ii)calculate avg of predictions $\bar y$ across datasets' ($\mathbf L$ = 100) models -> iii): calculate the MSE of (model's prediction - $\bar y$) i.e. 100 squared terms (*for each of these 100 sum, $\bar y$ remains constant*.) 
Then take next point, move to step 2 - calculated avg prediction - and so on. Is my understanding right? Else, point out the gap(s). Regards

Comment: ..and so, implementation steps would be $\sum_{n=1}^N (\cdot) > \bar y(\cdot) > \sum_{l=1}^L (\cdot)$ i.e. take a point > calculate 100 models' predication mean > calculate MSE. Is my understanding correct. Would appreciate your input. Regards.